# What are some possibilities for handling URL requests to an Angular 5 application?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, apache, .htaccess

I'm developing an Angular 5 application and I've built it and dropped the contents of the `dist/` directory onto a docker container.

When I navigate the app using the app's navigation (utilizing `routerLink`) there's no issue with finding the page you are looking for. The reason there is no problem is because Angular manipulates the DOM based on user interaction.

But if the user hits the refresh button on a page other than the index.html, the web server sends a 404 page. This is because Apache (or I guess any server OS) is looking for a page "file" that doesn't exist. Angular's router is in the JavaScript package sent to the browser. Since it isn't on the server, when the server receives a request for a path that isn't index.html, it doesn't find anything in .htaccess and simply returns the 404.

One solution to this problem would be to update the .htaccess file with all of the routes of the Angular application so that it redirects all routes to the index.html. This seems kind of messy though. And how would you preserve the request for the specific page and feed it to Angular?

**So the question:** Is there a way to make apache aware of an internal page in an Angular app and load the Angular app at that page? Or is .htaccess modification the only way?

Comment: With Angular you always redirect all calls that come to the serve to your index.html. I.e. Hitting refresh sends the route to the server, you them direct all routes received by the server to Angular. Except of course routes used to retrieve data i.e. api calls. I think this is what you are asking about. So in essence  yes update the htaccess to direct all calls to angular.

Comment: depends on whether you have access to apache config or not. `.htaccess` is very common approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` rewrite is pretty much the goto solution.  [This page](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2) describes it pretty well.